# making this piece of code so that it will read the first 8 bytes of the given file

Tags: java, io

i need this code to output the first 8 bytes of a given file, i'm sure it will be just one line, any help would be much appreciated.

```
import java.io.*;

public class FileInHexadecimal {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("c:\\open.gif");
                for(int i=0; i<=8; i++)
                {
                        fis.read();
                        if (i != -1) {
                                System.out.println(i); 
                        }
                }
                fis.close();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need at least 3 lines

```
    byte[] a = new byte[8];
    fis.read(a);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to do something with the value returned from `fis.read()`. This is the value you should be printing out, instead of your loop counter `i`.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.io.*;

public class FileInHexadecimal {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("c:\\open.gif");
                for(int i=0; i < 8; i++)
                {
                        System.out.println(fis.read()); 
                }
                fis.close();
        }
}
```

Should work. Print what you read, not the counter. You don't need to check it since it will always count from 0 to 7 (8 bytes). You could add checks for what you actually read though if you wish...